# SRS warning light

Tags: chevrolet, trailblazer

I recently replaced the instrument cluster in my 2004 trailblazer and the SRS warning is on. I'm thinking that it's because the trailblazer I took it out of had deployed the airbag. Is there a way to reset the light because there's nothing wrong with my airbag.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

If there aren't any problems with your supplemental restraint system (SRS), you'll need to get an OBDII scanner which will clear SRS codes. Most standard scanners won't do this, you have to get one which is specific for clearing SRS codes. Most of these will also deal with anti-lock braking system (ABS) codes as well. There are quite a few on the market which don't cost too much, such as Innova or TOPDON (no affiliation with either).

While you can clear regular OBDII codes by pulling the battery connection, this won't work for SRS, so you'll need a scanner which can handle the job.